# Dependency on a macro

Tags: android, makefile

I saw this line in build/core/java.mk of Android source:

```
$(full_classes_compiled_jar): PRIVATE_JAVAC_DEBUG_FLAGS := -g
```

What does it mean to depend on a macro rather than a real file?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found the answer. It is a [target-specific variable](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-3-SECT-5).